# All the contents (of other pages) of my website sits under the same tab unless an user clicks on the tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, tabs

I am having an issue with my newly published website. As soon as the site is loaded it shows all the contents including paragraph, videos (from other pages as well) etc.. under one single tab (in my case it HOME tab). But once any tab is clicked its fixed automatically. Please look [here](http://www.jabiralfatah.com/).

So, it's a problem! I want the contents previously fixed (shouldn't wait for an user click).

Now I am well aware of my design. I haven't used multiple pages link. I stored everything in my main index file and used the following jQuery code to just redirect them to the corresponding section (after clicking a corresponding tab):

Please help me to improve the code so that my page loads as I want.

I guess my issue is related with this piece of code:

```
    /*Make the tabs work-begins*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#all_contents>div').filter(':first').show();
$('ul>li>a').click(function () {
        $('#all_contents>div').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $(target).show();
        return false;
    });
 });
 /*Make the tabs work-ends*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide all the divs and then show only the first div inside #all_contents. This should do the trick:

```
/*Make the tabs work-begins*/
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Hide all divs first
  $('#all_contents>div').hide();                 

  //Then show only first
  $('#all_contents>div').filter(':first').show();

  $('ul>li>a').click(function () {
        $('#all_contents>div').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $(target).show();
        return false;
    });
});
/*Make the tabs work-ends*/
```

Comment: great my friend, i did it and works fine. Many many loves and respect to YOU! However i have more than 100 images to upload into the webserver. Could you tell me  the easiest way to upload them alltogether. I haven't done it yet, because I dont know the superior way to do that.  Finally check the final look you helped to fix: http://www.jabiralfatah.com/

Comment: well, you could zip them into a single file, upload the zip and then un-zip from the server ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all of the contents initially then you should apply the css styles added by clicking home to your html rather than applying it on js load:

```
$('ul>li>a').click(function () {
    $('#all_contents>div').hide();
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.attr('href');
    $(target).show();
    return false;
 });
});
```

So this hides all pages except the one which was clicked by adding the style `display:none;` inline to all of the selected elements. Because tehy aren't hidden on page load, the site only works after clicking on a link. You should do the same, but add the style as a rule in your css rather than in-lining:

```
#all_contents > div {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also appreciable. I just tried the Amit's answer first and it worked. But i will keep your suggestion in mind, in case for further use.

Comment: Cheers, they are both the same answer tbh, the only difference is that mine will apply immediately while Amit's will be applied on JS execution, but seeing as your site completely relies on JS this isn't really an issue.